# Can Svelte select elements contain buttons?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to insert buttons into select items [such as this](https://svelte.dev/repl/fabd0a84b1b244f2925c1431ae9ec4c5?version=3.12.1). I'd like each element to have a button so that a different action can be taken if the button is clicked, such as removing that item from the list. If I put the code for the button in the label field then the button shows up but it doesn't handle the `on:click` directive.

Comment: Show your attempt.

Comment: This is what I've tried. https://svelte.dev/repl/41660002e5114bd2a1473f6288b0121e?version=3.12.1

Answer (score 0):

first try css , test peroperty z-index: 9999; for close button .

if css peroperty not working try to console.log('someting') if close button with click event in javascript ; and if you got console.log('someting');

now you can write fucntion to close your item;

i hope i can alitel help;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this.

This library expects the `value` to be a string, at most a html script for some extra styling, but you cannot add interactions like that.

The code you have is similar to do doing:

```html
<script>
  const str = "<button on:click={console.log}>click me</button>"
</script>

{@html str}
```

While this will *render* a button Svelte will not add the event handler to this, but rather just render the string as you gave it (in face if you inspect the rendered markup you will still the `on:click` written there)